# perfect forwarding with brace enclosed initialiser list

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, list-initialization

For personal education I am coding up a basic implementation of a hash table (although the below is probably relevant to any container that is holding types that can be list initialised) and want to use modern elements of c++ as best as I understand them - in particular in this case, perfect forwarding.

In doing so I have found I can't figure out a particular case - writing an insert function that achieves perfect forwarding while taking a brace enclosed initialiser list. Failing to write this prevents using perfect forwarding when trying to emulate the `std::unordered_map` like insertion style `container.insert({key,value})`.

To be specific, I have some hash table class which stores keys and values as `std::pair<T,U>` objects in (for example) lists at buckets stored in a vector (for a hash+chaining approach)

```
template<typename T,typename U, typename func = std::hash<T> >
class HashTable{
    std::vector<std::list<std::pair<T,U> > > data;
...
public: 
    template<typename V>
    bool insert(V &&entry)
    {
        //insert into the table by forwarding entry as
        ... = std::forward<V>(entry);
        return true; //plus some logic for failed insertion if key already exists
    }
};
```

I then test my container by inserting with both lvalues and rvalues through calls such as

```
std::pair<int32_t,std::string> example = {12,"bike"};
myHashTableObject.insert(example);                                  //example 1
myHashTableObject.insert(std::pair<int32_t,std::string>(15,"car")); //example 2
myHashTableObject.insert({28,"bus"});                               //example 3
```

Examples 1 and 2 compile and work fine, but example 3 does not with compiler error (for example using the default type for the third template argument `func` - but the error is analgous for user provided hashes)

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘HashTable<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::insert(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

which seems reasonable - it can't figure out how to interpret what type of object the initialisation list is supposed to construct.

An easy "solution" is to forget perfect forwarding and just overload the `insert` function to accept a rvalue reference and a const lvalue reference to a `std::pair<T,U>`. But it feels like there should be a better way.

Is there an obvious way to inform the compiler that, despite being a template variable `V` in order to achieve perfect forwarding, it should be some kind of reference to a `std::pair<T,U>` argument?

How do common implementations of containers in STL achieve this? Or do they just overload?

Comment: If your only `insert` function is `template<class T> bool insert(V &&entry)`, then you cannot call it like `insert({28,"bus"});` because the braces are an undeduced context and the type of `entry` remains unknown.

Comment: *"Or do they just overload?"* As a data point [std::unordered_map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) has 8 overloads.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{..}` has not type, and so cannot be deduced in `insert`.

You might work around that by providing default template type:

```
template<typename V = std::pair<T, U>> // default to handle {..}
bool insert(V&& entry)
{
    ... = std::forward<V>(entry);
    // ..
    return true;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Te485G79)